# Need help adding decimals to yaxis values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Morning! First post on here:) I am working with chart.js V1 and can't figure out how to add decimals to the calculated values on the yaxis. 
I am looking to have them go as so:

200.00 - two 0's after decimal

40.0% - one 0 after decimal

I figured out how to get thew % in there but not the decimals. I have attached some code for one of my graphs.

Thanks for any help!

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data 1",
      lineTension: 0,
      borderColor: "rgba(0,145,179,1)",
      pointRadius: 0,
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: [18, 24, 21, 17, 9, 13, 8.5, 10, 9.5, 13, 5]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
      bezierCurve: false,
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
          fontStyle: "normal",
          fontSize: "15",
          beginAtZero: true,
          padding: 7,
          max: 30,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 5,
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Maternal Deaths per 10.000 Deliveries',
          fontSize: 18,
          padding: 30,
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false,
          display: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false,
          display: false,
          zeroLineColor: "transparent"
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 7,
          fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
          fontStyle: "normal",
          fontSize: "15"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand your rules with two examples. Do you want to attach '.00' to a 3-digit-number and '.0%' to a 2-digit-number? Btw your code is missing a few braces. It's not exetutable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will need them in four ways. 40.0, 600.0, 9.00, 3.50. Some have % some don't. Yes all the code ins't there. I didn't copy all the brackets just the sections i thought would help and show what I have. When making my first post it said not to place all the code so I tried what I thought to do.

Comment: Here is a live link to one of the graphs. 

http://offers.premierinc.com/graph-test_graph-test.html

I had to upload this as a test page in Marketo sorry. The only way I can create a live link at the moment.

Comment: Can you explain how the decimals are working for you , i mean the rules , it is pretty unclear to me , because sometimes you are appending a single 0 (.0) and sometimes you are doing double 0 (.00)

Comment: To be honest I have no idea why some have .0 and some .00. I was given a screenshot and told to animate it exactly how it looks. Is there an option or function that can be added in the .js to add them to the calculated data on the yaxis? For instance I used this to add the %.

callback: function(tick) {
          return tick.toString() + '%';
        }

Maybe something similiar to add the decimals? I'm not that savy with .js.

Comment: `ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value.toFixed(n);
                    }
                }`
Here n is the number of decimals you want.

Comment: WOW! So all I would do is add two n's (nn) to have two decimals at the end and one (n) for one decimal? Sorry if that is a stupid question.

Comment: `n`is the count of the decimals. If you say `return value.toFixed(2)` every number will have 2 decimals.

Comment: Read about toFixed here `https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp`

Answer (score 1):

Here is jsfiddle [Adding decimal places to chart.js axis](https://jsfiddle.net/tkhosla/bo1L2d3v/)

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Data 1",
    lineTension: 0,
    borderColor: "rgba(0,145,179,1)",
    pointRadius: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2,
    data: [18, 24, 21, 17, 9, 13, 8.5, 10, 9.5, 13, 5]
  }]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
      bezierCurve: false,
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value.toFixed(2);
          },
          fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
          fontStyle: "normal",
          fontSize: "15",
          beginAtZero: true,
          padding: 7,
          max: 30,
          min: 0,
          stepSize: 5
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Maternal Deaths per 10.000 Deliveries',
          fontSize: 18,
          padding: 30
        },
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false,
          display: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawTicks: false,
          display: false,
          zeroLineColor: "transparent"
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 7,
          fontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)",
          fontStyle: "normal",
          fontSize: "15",
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!! One more question. Is it possible to have the decimals and the % sign? I had to remove this below to get your new callback to work. 

callback: function(tick) {
          return tick.toString() + '%';
 
        }

Comment: Figured out how to add % with a decimal:

callback:function(value, index, values) {

return value.toFixed(2) + "%";

Thanks for all your help everyone!!!